# Using Sitecore $ variables

Tags: sitecore

Is there a site/link that defines how to create and use the $variables in Sitecore?  I'm looking for a complete list of variables and how to define custom variables.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to learn more about **Sitecore tokens**.

OOTB there are 6 tokens in Sitecore. In alphabetical order:

- $date – server date
- $id – current item id
- $name – current item name
- $now – server datetime
- $parentid – parent item id
- $parentname – parent item name
- $time – server time

When they are used as a value of field on `__Standard Value` item of a template and user creates an item using that template, tokens are "translated" into appropriate values.

More about tokens and how to create custom tokens:

- https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/add-custom-standard-values-tokens-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms
- https://sitecorecorner.com/2014/08/03/sitecore-custom-tokens/
- https://soen.ghost.io/working-with-custom-tokens-in-sitecore/

Comment: Thanks Marek.  I wasn't familiar with the proper name for these.  I'll research these sites.